# confused about compile time constants

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, linker, constants

As I read in a C++ book, the process of gcc is: Pre-Processing, `Compiling`, Assembling and Linking.

There are `Compile Time` constants and `Run Time` constants. Then I get confused about "Compiling" and "compile time". Please tell me what "compile time" means in the process of gcc, is it the whole of Pre-Processing, `Compiling`, Assembling and Linking?

Comment: I don't think these terms have fixed meanings. Compile time is usually contrasted with run time, so in that sense compile time would be as you stated.

Comment: C++ does distinguish between compile time constants and run-time constants. See my answer below

Comment: Let me know if anything doesn't make sense to you. I'm happy to elaborate. These are important concepts for people learning C++ and or bolstering their knowledge of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Compile Time" or "Compiling" is one part of the process. In C++, there is a feature called Macros that are expanded into C++ code during the Pre-Processor stage. This Pre-Processor stage runs first before the compiler. Depending on the compiler, the next step is to convert the human-readable C++ code to another form that is readable by machines. This really depends on the type of the compiler and other possible arguments passed in during compilation as to what this turns into. For sake of simplicity, let's assume the compiler compiles the C++ to symbols/assembly/machine code. Each of these files is independent, for lack of better term.

The last step is to 'link these together. Includes, forward declarations, and externs are resolved during this stage. The once independent files now 'linked' with sizes of types/classes/structs known at the end of the stage. After all this is done, an executable is formed for which is purely machine language and understood by the computer running the program.

A general rule of thumb for C++ programming is you want to catch as many errors as possible at compile time. Run-time is the span of time for which your program is executing the machine code. This can include heap allocations, dynamic list resizing, etc...

Now, to the crux of your question. What is the difference between a **Run-Time** constant and **Compile Time** constant? It is quite simple. **Compile Time** constants are values known and resolvable at compile time. These values can be determined and calculated and depend on no external user input or file data. See constexpr as a good reference for learning more about compile time constants: [ConstExprLink](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

```
const int userScore = 3; // Compile time constant
const int secondUserScore = 5; // Compile time constant
constexpr int CombinedUserScores = ( userScore + secondUserScore ); // Also compile constant because all values are known at compile time
```

However, there are some constants that cannot be known at compile time. These values can be determined and resolved after your program **Run-Time** begins. Now, in contrast, imagine you are reading user input or data from a file during Run-Time

```
std::cout << "Enter your Test Score: ";
const int testScore = 0;
std::cin >> testScore; // User sets an input value during Run-Time

const int userScore { testScore }; // Run-Time constant. No way to know the value at compile time
```

userScore is now a Run-Time constant that cannot be changed unless you engage in some taboo stuff like const_cast or C style casts. The point here is that the compiler has no way to know what the value of this constant would be until the input is read in. This is often called Data-Driven programming and is a very common paradigm. Also, because the **Run-Time** const is not determined at compile time, constexpr **cannot** be used here.

The above is an example of a **Run-Time** constant. This value cannot be resolved at compile time because the compiler has no idea what the input from the user or file might be. Here is another good reference: [CompileTimeConstant Versus RunTimeConstant](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/const-constexpr-and-symbolic-constants/)

Answer (score 0):

The different steps you described are as follows:

**Pre-processing:** This is just when text is literally replaced. For example, when you `#include` a header, the entire contents of that file is dumped right in that spot. Pre-processing can also be used to make "compile-time constants" with `#define`, but this is not a recommended practice for modern C++.

**Compiling:** To explain this simply (there are a lot of nuances to this), this is when your code is being turned into machine instructions for the architecture that you're compiling for.

**Assembling/Linking:** These are somewhat irrelevant to the question, but they are the final step to putting the pieces of the program together for the resulting executable.

There is some ambiguity in what this question is asking for, but for constants in general, runtime means that they are created after the program is started, compile-time means they are precomputed before the program starts (when the code is being compiled). Modern C++ introduces `constexpr` which lets you explicitly state that something should be initialized at compile time and be able to be passed around in compile-time computations.

Take the number pi for instance. Calculating this to the 20th digit takes a little time, but if it was declared as a compile time constant (e.g. `constexpr double pi = 3.14159...`), it's free and can also be mixed with any compile-time computations. This sort of stuff is being expanded a lot in the latest standards.

Runtime constants can't be used in compile-time calculations, because their value isn't known at compile time. `const` is used as a constraint to enforce that some variable cannot be changed, very commonly seen in function parameters to accept read-only references.